# Not able to run sql-script for database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to learn MVVM Pattern for WPF Applications in Visual Studio.

To this end I am doing an online course, which provides the source code for the course project under the following address:

https://github.com/briannoyes/WPFMVVM-StarterCode

I downloaded the project code and opened the project in Visual Studio.

So far so good.

Then I am supposed to create an empty database and run the ZzzDatabaseGen.sql. file, which was also provided under the above-mentioned link.

So I did the following steps:

1. Choose "Project"
2. Choose "Add New Item"
3. Select "Service-based Database"
4. In the Name area, I typed: Zza.mdf
5. Choose Add

Then I opened the file ZzzDatabaseGen.sql and executed it.

I receive an error message telling me that the database "Zza" doesn't exist.

What do I have to do to create a database, connect it to my project and be able to run the ZzzDatabaseGen.sql script so that all the tables are created?

Comment: Download and install the MS SQL of your choosing, Developer and Express are free...there will be loads of literature on how to do that. Once installed, you will need to create the database Zza - Once done, you can run the script ZzzDatabaseGen.sql script - as that script doesn't create the database, just the tables and inserts the data.

Answer (score 0):

Before running the script file you have to create the database in your SQL Server instance. 
So, for example, using the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS you can access all your local SQL Server Express instances.
Here, you can select the desired instance and click "New query".
To create a database for your purpose you can simply run this code:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Zza] ON  PRIMARY
( NAME = N'Zza', FILENAME = N'\Zza.mdf')
LOG ON
( NAME = N'Zza_log', FILENAME = N'\Zza_log.ldf')
GO
```

Of course you have to write the correct path to the mdf file you would like to create.

After that you can run the ZzzDatabaseGen.sql script to create the tables and insert all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Service-based database file (`Zza.mdf`) that you created in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and choose "Open". This should bring up the Server Explorer (`View`->`Server Explorer`).

Then you right-click on the `Zza.mdf` node in the server explorer and choose "New query". You should then be able to run the queries in the query window.

Press the green play arrow once you have pasted in the queries from the  `ZzzDatabaseGen.sql` script.